# Why does the previous page link appears in my address bar in MVC3 Razor application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, routes

I am using MVC3/Razor. But I don't understand why the previous page url appears when i redirecToAction.

Scenario: Once the user clicks on Signup from home page like "Account/Signup", the he would get RedirectToAction("AcceptCondition") so once the use accepts the condition and post then the user would get RedirectToAction("Signup") where i will check if he is coming from "AcceptCondition" page then he can proceed otherwise user will go back to "AcceptCondition" page. So when I redirect user from Signup page to AcceptCondition page the url in the address bar appears like "http://localhost:55104/Account/Signup" instead of "http://localhost:55104/Account/AcceptCondition"

I know that i can send user directly to "Account/AcceptCondition" when he click on the signup but I just followed upper scenario.

```
public ActionResult Signup(string ru)
{
    if ((ru == "/Account/AcceptCondition") || (ru == "/Account/Signup"))
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("AcceptCondition");
    }
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AcceptCondition()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AcceptCondition(AcceptConditionViewModel acceptCondiViewModel)
{
    if (acceptCondiViewModel.TermAndCondi == true)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Signup",  
                                "Account", 
                                new { ru = "/Account/AcceptCondition" });
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Signup GET checks refers, if not AcceptCondition, then redirects to AcceptCondition
   IF it is AcceptCondition, then render the normal signup view.
2. AcceptCondition GET renders the AcceptCondition view
3. AcceptCondition POST does RedirectToAction("SIGNUP")
4. Signup POST creates the user (Assuming) then goes?

Sounds like the referrer check isn't right so /account/signup is rendered again?
Whats your code look like.

Comment: check the question now modified.

Comment: Hi Adam is there anything you can help me with this? please check my code.

Comment: you are saying " return RedirectToAction("AcceptCondition");" doesn't work, right? set a breakpoint there. Ensure your view exists for "AcceptCondition.cshtml" in the /views/account folder

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are passing a parameter of 'returnUrl' in your first function, but reference it as 'ru' in both the function body and in your RedrectToAction call in the third function. Be sure you are staying consistent with your parameter names as this could be a cause of faulty logic and bad/not working redirects.

Comment: Please check the code i added. If you can help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to put a breakpoint in your first function and actually look at what the value of the ru variable is.  Ensure that your code is following the logic that you have set forth.